# File's owner belongs to the wrong class

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5

My iPhone app had the standard `ViewController.h`, `ViewController.m` and `ViewController.xib` to support the 3.5" retina display. I made a new `ViewController_5.h`, `ViewController_5.m`, `ViewController_5.xib` to support the 4" display on the iPhone 5. In theory, these should be totally independent of each other. But now, `IBActions` from the `ViewController_5.h` show up in `ViewController_5.xib`, and when I connect them I expect the action to carry out whatever is in `ViewController_5.m`. But it actually does the code in `ViewController.m`. What's going on here?

Comment: What is the name of the xib file for ViewController_5? You wrote ViewController.xib, is that right or a typo?

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how your app is selecting the appropriate VC & NIB?

Comment: @rdelmar it's right, I have two ViewControllers to handle the two different screen sizes. @J Shapiro the code looks like this:

Comment: if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 480) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_5" bundle:nil];
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you posted it looks like you just need to supply the right view controller class (ViewController_5) in the else part of your if statement, like this

```
... else { self.viewController = [[ViewController_5 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_5" bundle:nil]; }
```